# Is it possible to send email notifications through SNS or SQS whenever a 0 kb file uploade into s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

whenever a 0 kb file or invalid file uploaded into s3 bucket client has to recieve a email notification through SNS or SQS.Is it possible without using Aws Lambda???

Thanks in Advance!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an s3 event notification, you can setup an SNS  easily to notify you each time a file is uploaded - but something needs to look at that object/file and determine its size - it doesn't need to be Lambda, but it needs to be something.

So for example, s3 notification could put a message in an SQS queue, another custom process running (on ec2 or anywhere else), could see the notification, and use information in the message to look at the new s3 object and determine its size, and decide if an email needs to be sent - but unless you have a good reason not to use Lambda, Lambda is probably the easiest way.

So yes it possible, but the alternative methods are more work than just using Lambda - but **you can't do it without Lambda or some other process adding the extra logic, nothing is built in to allow these conditional notifications**.